# Magento Local (localhost) Installation Customer Login

Tags: customer, login, localhost

I have a Magento local installation, but can't log in with customer user account on Chrome browser. Any fix? 
Registration works well on my localhost though, because I can verify the account from the back-end.

Comment: What are the settings for cookies in `System > Configuration` and what is the domain?

Comment: I believe you are referring to `System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management`. And its `localhost`.
I just tried changing `Use HTTP Only` from `YES` to `NO`, and i can now log in successfully as a a customer on localhost.

Comment: Welcome to Magento.SE @ONOCHIE! Some of our users believe this question may be off topic. I don't believe that to be the case, but if you were to edit your question to include the value of `System > Configuration > Web` it may help to target the answers more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried changing Use HTTP Only from YES to NO, and I can now log in successfully as a a customer on localhost.

Comment: This is not a fix; this **masks part of the problem** with Magento and the very well documented issues with logging in and cookie problems with not having a dot somewhere in the url. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80373/base-url-error-when-localhost